# Comma-separated List of Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly basic query that essentially returns a `SUM` total for invoice line net, for each customer, where there was a certain discount given.

As part of this, I want to return the invoice numbers that each discount applied to, as a comma separated list.

This is essential as it's being fed into another piece of software that only accepts the data in this format.

I could format in Excel as this is where the data will end up, however I'd rather do it in the query directly.

I'm getting my head muddled trying to use the `FOR XML PATH` function to do this.

Below is the current query, which returns one row per Discount Group, Customer, Discount % given with the sum totals

Field for invoice number is invoice_header.ih_number

```
SELECT  variant_discount_group.vdg_node_path AS 'Discount Group' ,
        customer_detail.cd_statement_name AS 'Customer Name' ,
        invoice_line_item.ili_discount_percent AS 'Discount' ,
        SUM(( CASE WHEN invoice_header.ih_credit = 1 THEN -1
                   ELSE 1
              END ) * invoice_line_item.ili_qty) AS 'Qty' ,
        SUM(( CASE WHEN invoice_header.ih_credit = 1 THEN -1
                   ELSE 1
              END ) * invoice_line_item.ili_net) AS 'Total Net'
FROM    invoice_header
        JOIN invoice_line_item ON invoice_line_item.ili_ih_id = invoice_header.ih_id
        JOIN variant_detail ON variant_detail.vad_id = invoice_line_item.ili_vad_id
        JOIN variant_setting ON variant_setting.vas_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
        JOIN customer_detail ON customer_detail.cd_id = invoice_header.ih_cd_id
        LEFT JOIN variant_discount_group ON variant_discount_group.vdg_id = variant_setting.vas_vdg_id
WHERE   invoice_header.ih_datetime BETWEEN @DateFrom
                                   AND     @DateTo
        AND ISNULL(variant_discount_group.vdg_node_path, '') LIKE @VDGroup
        + '%'
        AND invoice_line_item.ili_discount_percent BETWEEN @DiscFrom
                                                   AND    @DiscTo
GROUP BY variant_discount_group.vdg_node_path ,
        customer_detail.cd_statement_name ,
        invoice_line_item.ili_discount_percent
ORDER BY variant_discount_group.vdg_node_path ,
        customer_detail.cd_statement_name ,
        invoice_line_item.ili_discount_percent
```

Comment: can you provide with the Sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   variant_discount_group.vdg_node_path AS [Discount Group] ,
                        customer_detail.cd_statement_name AS [Customer Name] ,
                        invoice_line_item.ili_discount_percent AS [Discount] ,
                        ( CASE WHEN invoice_header.ih_credit = 1 THEN -1
                               ELSE 1
                          END ) * invoice_line_item.ili_qty AS [Qty] ,
                        ( CASE WHEN invoice_header.ih_credit = 1 THEN -1
                               ELSE 1
                          END ) * invoice_line_item.ili_net AS [Total Net] ,
                        invoice_header.ih_number AS [invoice]
               FROM     invoice_header
                        JOIN invoice_line_item ON invoice_line_item.ili_ih_id = invoice_header.ih_id
                        JOIN variant_detail ON variant_detail.vad_id = invoice_line_item.ili_vad_id
                        JOIN variant_setting ON variant_setting.vas_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
                        JOIN customer_detail ON customer_detail.cd_id = invoice_header.ih_cd_id
                        LEFT JOIN variant_discount_group ON variant_discount_group.vdg_id = variant_setting.vas_vdg_id
               WHERE    invoice_header.ih_datetime BETWEEN @DateFrom
                                                   AND     @DateTo
                        AND ISNULL(variant_discount_group.vdg_node_path, '') LIKE @VDGroup
                        + '%'
                        AND invoice_line_item.ili_discount_percent BETWEEN @DiscFrom
                                                              AND
                                                              @DiscTo
             )
    SELECT  a.[Discount Group] ,
            a.[Customer Name] ,
            a.[Discount] ,
            SUM(a.[Qty]) AS Qty ,
            SUM(a.[Total Net]) AS [Total Net] ,
            SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.[invoice])
                        FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                        [invoice],
                                        [Discount Group], 
                                        [Customer Name], 
                                        [Discount]
                                 FROM cte) AS b
                        WHERE   a.[Discount Group] = b.[Discount Group]
                                AND a.[Customer Name] = b.[Customer Name]
                                AND a.[Discount] = b.[Discount]
                      FOR
                        XML PATH('')
                      ), 2, 1000) AS [List of invoices]
    FROM    cte AS a
    GROUP BY a.[Discount Group] ,
            a.[Customer Name] ,
            a.[Discount]
    ORDER BY a.[Discount Group] ,
            a.[Customer Name] ,
            a.[Discount]
```

Comment: Runs fast and works great thanks. Much better than my attempt.

Comment: Actually, one thing. If 2 items in the same discount group are on one invoice, the invoice number is repeated within the substring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about performance issues but you could create a function returning a VARCHAR. Call that function in your select statement and as parameter give your reference for your invoicenumbers.

in the Function you would have a cursor for all rows of Invoicenumbers and iterate over it and concatenate into the return value.

This is probably quick and dirty and ressource intensive.

Comment: I can't create functions on the DB unfortunately.

Comment: thinking about it, you could probably pivot the rows for invoicenumber und just concat them in your select. [link]https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396[/link]

Comment: I don't know how many invoice numbers there will be.
It could be 1, could be 50.

Comment: OK, so plz just give an example by creating it on www.sqlfiddle.com thx.